# Legal term for negotiator

Tags: united-states, contract-law, legal-terms

For some reason I've been looking for an official term for a person or company (agent?) acting on behalf of other organization (principal?). Example is company A wants to construct a factory in country C. So company A hires company B to negotiate with officials of country C to make an agreement.

Can you please provide a document with the term, esp. contracts, if possible?

Comment: Agent**********

Comment: In addition to the terms in the answer, the term "broker" or somewhat archaically in U.S. practice, "factor" also have these meanings. This job is also often handled by an "attorney at law" instead of an agent a.k.a. attorney in fact who is not an attorney. "Contractor" is another term often used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard  legal term you are probably looking for to describe Company B is "[attorney-in-fact](http://thelawdictionary.org/attorney-in-fact/)."

For contract purposes you can call the parties whatever you want.  These are "defined terms," and what matters are the rights and responsibilities as enumerated in any contract.  E.g., you could define Company B as "The Big Kahuna" and as long as that term is used consistently in the contract it's legally as good as any other.

Other common terms could certainly include "Agent," "Negotiator," or "Intermediary."